# How many days it will take to change the old passport number to new passport number in Singapore visa?

Tags: visas, singapore

I live in Bangalore. I need to change  the old passport number to new passport number in Singapore visa?
Tomorrow I will receive my passport and my travel date to Singapore is on 15april.

Answer (score 1):

You have to obtain a new visa. From my experience, it can take from a couple of days to one week. So, just rush for that. Alternatively, if a Singapore citizen or PR can vouch for you, they can apply the visa online and it will take only one day or less.

From the Singapore ICA website,

> Q13:  **How do I transfer my valid visa issued on my old travel document
>   to the new one?**
>
> A: You must obtain a new visa if you are intending
>   to travel to Singapore with a different travel document from the one
>   submitted during the application for this visa You should obtain the
>   new visa before travelling to Singapore. You may approach the nearest
>   Singapore Overseas Mission or through the authorized visa agents of
>   the Overseas Missions for the details. Basic supporting documents
>   require from you are : old and new travel document (original and
>   copy), the valid visa, Form 14A duly completed and signed, photograph.
>   The photograph should be a recent passport-sized colour photograph
>   taken within the last 3 months and must be taken against a white
>   background with a matt or semi-matt finish.

https://eservices.ica.gov.sg/save-public/xhtml/common/FAQ.xhtml#13